# CAST CASE statement exceeding limit

Tags: sql, casting, case, cognos, tidy

I'd like to built a report that gives me the job description types all in 1 row (tidy format) vs. having multiple rows per job title. 
The current report gives me:

```
Job Title    Description Type    Posting Description
Cook         Responsibilities    Make food
Cook         Requirements        3 Years of Experience
```

Desired output is:

```
Job Title    Responsibilities    Requirements 
Cook         Make food           3 Years of Experience
```

I first tried a basic CASE statement that uses but learned on here I need to use CAST. But when I do that I get errors. With what I currently have, the full string for posting description comes through. I'm not sure how to fix this.

BONUS: The string contains HTML text... If someone could tell me that, it'd be a big help.

```
CAST(
CASE WHEN ([Description Type Number] =3)
THEN [Enterprise Staffing].[Job Opening].[Posting Description]
END 
AS VARCHAR(20))
```

RESULTING ERROR
RQP-DEF-0177 An error occurred while performing operation 'sqlOpenResult' status='-9'.
UDA-SQL-0107 A general exception has occurred during the operation "open result".
ORA-22835: Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW conversion (actual: 6747, maximum: 4000)

```
CAST(
CASE WHEN ([Description Type Number] =3)
THEN [Enterprise Staffing].[Job Opening].[Posting Description]
END 
AS CHAR)
```

RESULTING ERROR
RQP-DEF-0177 An error occurred while performing operation 'sqlOpenResult' status='-9'.
UDA-SQL-0107 A general exception has occurred during the operation "open result".
ORA-25137: Data value out of range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:  That's a crosstab.  You may be overthinking this.

Second:  Know thy data.

It looks like [Posting Description] contains values as long as 6747 characters.  Based on the error message, it may be *text* or *ntext*.  varchar(20) is not long enough.  Trying to cast it to a char of unspecified length appears to cause different problems.  Assuming this is MS SQL Server, something like this may help:

```
CASE 
  WHEN ([Description Type Number] =3)
    THEN CAST([Enterprise Staffing].[Job Opening].[Posting Description], VARCHAR(8000))
  ELSE CAST('', VARCHAR(8000))
END
```

But you error message probably indicates Oracle database.  (`ORA-52137`)

```
CASE 
  WHEN ([Description Type Number] =3)
    THEN CAST((substr([Enterprise Staffing].[Job Opening].[Posting Description], 1, 4000), VARCHAR2(4000))
  ELSE CAST('', VARCHAR2(4000))
END
```

Also, CAST in Cognos uses a comma, not *AS*.

Comment: Thanks, this got me going in the right direction, varchar(4000) was still causing errors so I brought it down to varchar(3800) and it worked.